# Shape of Input in Functional Keras

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, word-embedding

I want to do a word embedding + BLSTM in keras using a functional model. I have to declare the input as:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(X,))
```

Which should be the value of `X` here? Since the inputs will be sentences, I am not very sure what I should put in there.

Answer (score 1):

For [Keras LSTM](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) the input tensor must be of dimensions `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`. If you are not using `stateful=True` then specify `batch_size` of `None`, e.g. `inputs = Input(shape=(None, Tx, Xn))`, where `Tx` is the sentence length. `Xn` is going to be the word index which you then map through `Embedding` layer.

See [Using pre-trained word embeddings in a Keras model](https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html) for details of how to feed sentences into `Embedding` layer.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way or the other keras always need multidimensional numpy arraysas input.
The first dimension, which you don't have to specify is the batch_size. Keras will set it automatically to None.

I don't know how you want to do your embedding but one thing you could insert is something like this: (batch_size, len of sentence, number of characters)
then your X would be (len of sentence, number of characters)